# unable to find GCP Environment Variable for FUNCTION_TIMEOUT_SEC specifically for Node.js 10.x and 12.x

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

The environment variable- FUNCTION_TIMEOUT_SEC is set automatically for the Node.js 6, Node.js 8, Python 3.7 and Go 1.11 runtimes.
But for Node.js 10, there is not variable which gives the timeout value.

The Node.js 10 runtime automatically sets fewer environment variables than previous runtimes supported by Cloud Functions.

I am looking for a way to get the timeout value for GCP function for Node.js 10

is there any solution for this

Answer (score 1):

From this [document](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var) I find the [advice](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#best_practices_and_reserved_environment_variables) . This is described as a way to proceed.